# ScrollView is eating Swipe Gesture Recognizer

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

i have a details view controller with a scrollview on it. And i have load UILabel, UIImageView on top of UIScrollView. The scrollview is set to scroll vertically only. and the view need to be able to recognize swipe left and right to navigate to next/previous page by adding

```
self.leftGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(swipeRecognizer:)];
[self.leftGestureRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.leftGestureRecognizer];
```

So when i swipe within UILabel, it is working. If i swipe start from UIScrollView, it is not working. I guess it is the UIScrollView conflict the swipe gesture.

In short, swipe gesture is only working on the subview but not UIScrollView .Does anyone have any idea on this?

UPDATE:
If i swipe start from scrollview first then end at UILabel, it won't recognize the swipe gesture. If i swipe within UILabel(start and end in the UILAbel) it is able to recognize.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if the UIImage allows zooming, the swipe recognizer won't work, since it is trying to zoom. If this is the case, you will need to enable the zoom only in certain case. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the scroll view with scrolling disabled. Then you need to disable scrolling in the scroll view when the image is not zoomed in, and renabled it when it is zoomed in. This provides the expected behavior.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  if (scrollView.zoomScale != 1.0) {
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
  } else {
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
  }
}
```

To enable zoom provide an image on a delegate.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  return myImage;
}
```

Also add the gesture to instance of scrollview like this -

```
leftGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
[myScrollView addGestureRecognizer:leftGestureRecognizer];
```

**OR You can try the following -**

```
[scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail: leftGestureRecognizer]
```